# Cypress_- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: api, automation, cypress, matomo, piwiktracker

My UI page keeps on loading when I try to perform a click operation. Which in return needs to fetch data using API call in the back end and display it in UI. Attached screenshot for reference.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://idp2.renault.com/nidp//app/login?target=https%3A%2F%2Fidp2.renault.com%2Fnidp%2Foauth%2Fnam%2Fauthz%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2Bemail%2Bopenid%2Barca%2Brole-eic-irn65553%26client_id%3Da6a57638-bb90-49b8-b11b-862c9824fa13%26state%3DhGLwfzSpJOUeEw1dk5GOnFfN5L8%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Feic-app2.dev1.applis.renault.fr%3A443%2Fauth%2Foidc%26nonce%3DFiGw4mp9izHujzUrQVgEA7q9SOwUETofvF-5kDVqZqg%26resourceServer%3DIdentityProvider' (redirected from 'https://eic-app2.dev1.applis.renault.fr/assets/i18n/fr.json') from origin 'https://eic-app2.dev1.applis.renault.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue with the same error message. My symfony php backend is running locally in docker. XDebug is also installed. Following 2 lines in the backend resolved this issue and I was finally able to login.

```
touch /var/www/html/xdebug.log
chmod 777 /var/www/html/xdebug.log
```